# Mathematical definition of "confusable classes"

Tags: classification, multi-class

I have seen this term in this paper http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/gupta14a/gupta14a.pdf and I was wondering if there was a formal definition (I have an intuitive understanding, but something more formal would be nice).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can define this for a given classifier in terms of the confusion matrix. Confusable classes would be classes that correspond to rows/columns of large non-diagonal elements.
Thr level you would start calling them *highly* confusable etc. is arbitrary.